# Как настроить минимизацию css на выходе из webpack?

Tags: css, webpack

Настроил webpack + postcss/autoprefixer/cssnano на плагине `mini-css-extract-plugin`, выдержка из `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
    test: /\.((s[ac]|c)ss)$/,
    use: [
        plugins.extractCSS.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
                plugins: (() => {
                    return isProduction ? [
                        require('autoprefixer')(),
                        require('cssnano')({
                            preset: ['default', {
                                minifySelectors: false
                            }]
                        })
                    ] : []
                })()
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                sourceMap: !isProduction
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

SCSS на входе:

```
.test_1 {
    color: red;
}

.test_2 {
    color: green;
}

body {
    .test_3 {
        color: red;
    }

    .test_4 {
        color: red;
    }

    .test_5 {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

CSS на выходе:

```
.test_1 {
    color: red
}

.test_2 {
    color: green
}

body .test_3, body .test_4 {
    color: red
}

body .test_5 {
    color: green
}
```

Но если практично посмотреть на классы и их свойства, то можно оптимизировать и их, например так:

```
.test_1, body .test_3, body .test_4 {
    color: red
}

.test_2, body .test_5, {
    color: green
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Стоит ли так оптимизировать css на выходе?
2. Как настроить подобную оптимизацию в cssnano (или в другом плагине)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать при помощи `cssnano` [называется](https://cssnano.co/optimisations/mergeidents/) `mergeidents`.
Судя по [документации](https://cssnano.co/guides/optimisations), вам нужна [advanced](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssnano-preset-advanced#usage) версия.

1. Если вы хотите оптимизировать CSS для скорости загрузки для `production` то лучше использовать весь арсенал оптимизации (удаление пробелов и табов, сведение селекторов и свойств, конвертация gzip). Если же это компиляция для `dev` окружения то данная оптимизация будет создавать небольшой дискомфорт при работе из отладчика браузера.
2. Эта оптимизация [включена](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssnano-preset-advanced#postcss-merge-rules) по умолчанию в `advanced` версию